# Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-admin\mapred\staging\admin1774119027\.staging to 0700

Tags: hadoop

i am using hadoop 1.1.2, i coud not see the "staging" path ,i could see system path insteadof staging .any help here

```
13/07/12 18:49:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/07/12 18:49:43 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:gopalgdu cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-admin\mapred\staging\admin1774119027\.staging to 0700
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-admin\mapred\staging\admin1774119027\.staging to 0700
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:918)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1323)
    at com.hp.RecordCount.main(RecordCount.java:48)
```

Comment: I am getting this with version 1.2.1 as well. I am on windows attempting to run the job through Cygwin. Did you ever get past this issue?

Comment: did u proivide write permission to tmp folder?